# jdbctemplate equivalent of following query

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a long list of argument which I need to send to oracle database. I was able to do it by splitting the query but I am unable to find a way to do similar using jdbcTemplate. my query is:

```
select name,age from person where personId in (A1,F2,D3...G900) 
or personId in (A901, C902 , ... R1800) 
or personId in (A1801,G1802 .... H2700)
or personId in (P2701, G2702 ... R3600)
```

or since oracle allow more than 1000 touple but does not allow in so JDBC equivalent for

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM table1
WHERE (1, name) IN ((1, value1), (1, value2), (1, value3),.....(1, value5000));
```

Comment: Can you use WHERE id > 1 AND id < 10000

Comment: no I can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> findPeeps(List<Long> personIds) {
    String sql = "select name,age from person where personId in (:personIds)";
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new MapSqlParameterSource("personIds", personIds));
}
```

Comment: can this take more than than 1000 records ?

Comment: Problem with this solution is Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Comment: @ashish How many elements do you expect to have in the input?

Comment: @ashish Figure a way to have your collection containing all the input personIds split into multiple collections of a thousand elements each (since Oracle allows a maximum of 1,000 in the IN clause). Build the SQL string with placeholders for each of these collections, and then pass it on to jdbcTemplate with actual placeholder values (the collections obtained after splitting) as shown in my answer above.

Comment: I am expecting 60K records to be passed, the problem is the account I am using can't create temp table so creating temp table is out of picture.

Answer (score 0):

As @zaki said you can use that but the error that you are getting is from Oracle since there is limit of records you can put in WHERE IN clause. You can try something like this

```
insert into TEMP values ( ... );
 select * from T where (a,b) in (select x,y from temp);
 delete from TEMP;
```

Comment: I can not create the database table as my account does not have access to create it

Comment: Then you will have to manually create query string based on ids you have and either use OR or UNION. SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN (1,2,3) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM WHERE id IN (4,5,6).     Something like that

Comment: however problem again is how do I convert it into jdbctemplate ?